# How do you get block dimensions in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, width

I'm using a block for emphasizing different pieces of information. I'd like those pieces to be constrained to the block dimensions and to use the columns environment, but I don't know how to get the block dimensions in order to constraint the column's width.

```
\begin{block}
   \begin{columns}[t]
      \column{.3XXX} 
         Blah blah
      \column{.3XXX} 
         Blah blah
      \column{.3XXX} 
         Blah blah
   \end{columns}
\end{block}
```

How can I specify the column width based on the block width?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `totalwidth=\linewidth` option to your `columns` environment. Then you can use `\linewidth` as reference.

[image: example]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Columns in block}
  \begin{block}{A}
    \begin{columns}[totalwidth=\linewidth,t]
      \column{.3\linewidth} 
      Blah blah
      Blah blah
      Blah blah
      \column{.3\linewidth} 
      Blah blah
      Blah blah
      Blah blah
      Blah blah
      \column{.3\linewidth} 
      Blah blah
      Blah blah
      Blah blah
      Blah blah
    \end{columns}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there also a straightforward way to determine the height of a block?

Comment: @AndrewUzzell For what purpose?

Comment: I want to use it to set the height of an `\overlayarea`.  If this is non-trivial, I will ask it as a new question.

Comment: @AndrewUzzell Ok. You can ask a new question because this problem is not related to the current question/answer.