# How to determine the height of a beamer block?

Tags: beamer, overlays, height

To keep content from jumping between slides in a `beamer` presentation, I would like to use an `overlayarea` environment.  By trial and error, one can determine the appropriate amount of space to reserve.  However, I would like to determine it automatically.  To do this, I want to determine the height of one or more `block` environments.

In the following example, the position of "Some text" changes between the first and second slides.  I would like for it not to move.  To that end, I would like to enclose Block 1 and Block 2 in an `overlayarea`.  I want to determine the heights of Block 1 and Block 2, as well as the vertical space between them, and then use that as the height parameter for the `overlayarea`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Frankfurt}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 Some text

 \only<1>{
  \begin{block}{Block 1}
   Other text
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Block 2}
   Still more text
  \end{block}
}

  \only<2>{
    \begin{block}{Block 3}
     Yet more text
    \end{block}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is what I want to end up with:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Frankfurt}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 Some text

 \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\myheight} %\myheight is the quantity to be determined
   \only<1>{
  \begin{block}{Block 1}
   Other text
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Block 2}
   Still more text
  \end{block}
}

  \only<2>{
    \begin{block}{Block 3}
     Yet more text
    \end{block}
}
 \end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

N.B.: [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73045/13034) is about how to find the width of a `block`, but I have not found anything about finding the height.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it by boxing the content and then adding the depth and height of the box to obtain the total height:

```
\setbox0=\vtop{%
  \begin{block}{Block 1}
   Other text
  \end{block}%
}
\setlength{\myheight}{\ht0}%
\addtolength{\myheight}{\dp0}%
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Frankfurt}
}

\newlength{\myheight}
\begin{document}
\setbox0=\vtop{%
  \begin{block}{Block 1}
   Other text
  \end{block}%
}
\setlength{\myheight}{\ht0}%
\addtolength{\myheight}{\dp0}%

\begin{frame}
 Some text

 \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\myheight} %\myheight is the quantity to be determined
   \only<1>{
  \begin{block}{Block 1}
   Other text
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Block 2}
   Still more text
  \end{block}
}

  \only<2>{
    \begin{block}{Block 3}
     Yet more text
    \end{block}
}
 \end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of write `\only` command out of the block you should write `\uncover` or `\visible` command into the block. In this way latex will reserve enough space.

In your example, I do not clearly understand which block you want to keep fixed.

Comment: I want "Some text" to stay still.  I've edited my question to reflect that.